Importing .csv into PostgreSQL: ERROR: relation "zzz_dataset" does not exist SQL state: 42P01
New to PostgreSQL. I have a .csv that I want to import into PostgreSQL with the COPY command as follows:
COPY zzz_dataset
    FROM 'C:\Users\my_name\Desktop\SQL\zzz_delivery\zzz_dataset.csv'
    CSV HEADER;

The error that yielded was:
ERROR:  relation "zzz_dataset" does not exist 

SQL state: 42P01

I have also attempted the following with the same results:

Remove the indentation in Line 2 and 3
Added "" and '' in zzz_dataset
Added DELIMITER ',' in Line 3 instead
Used the Import Data wizard with UTF8 encoding, with Header turned on but it produced the following error:

ERROR: extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT: COPY zzz, line 2:

I am really quite clueless here, and I have tried looking at other similar threads. Would appreciate any help given, thanks!


relation "zzz_dataset" does not exist indicates that either the table does not exist or it named with mixed or upper case. In the latter case you will need to determine how it is actually named and double quote that name e.g. "ZZZ_DATASET". 2) As to second issue you will need to provide a sample of the CSV file, preferably something that includes line 2.


I am open to sharing the .csv in private but the names have been changed in my post to censor the brand. How do I share that with you?

You don't have to share the actual data, just a sample that has the same form: 1) Delimiter. 2) Number of columns. 3) Data form e.g. quotes, commas, etc. This extra data after last expected column generally means you have mismatch between the number of columns in the header and the number of data values in the data section. That could be because there are more data values then columns or due to data formatting 'creating' an extra data value.

I roughly understand your explanation, just hope that I understand your instructions correctly.

Delimiter: , (just placed comma because it's a csv)
Number of columns: 20
Data form: (Not sure what you mean)

This is a sample of the rows:
'0xcdcd DEHRES17DEL01 36 4.2 30.327968 78.046106 30.397968 78.116106 12/2/2022 21:55 22:10 Fog Jam 2 Snack motorcycle 3 No Metropolitian 46'

The data row has no commas for delimiters. Either you did not create a correct sample  or that is you problem. Just because something has a csv extension does  not it is guaranteed to be comma separated.

You have to create a table before you can load data into it.

I am aware that I need to create a table before loading the data. I will remove the DELIMITER row and try again. Do you know of any other solutions?


You need to read COPY. 2) Removing DELIMITER won't  change anything as  per the link in 1) the default delimiter for CSV is ,.  3) You need to determine what the delimiter is. If it is a tab then you may need to use TEXT instead of CSV. 4) If you have control over the program creating the file, then have it output what COPY is expecting.

